# Vue - Equation using props to assign class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a data table that I need to apply a class, dependent upon data that I'm passing to the data table.

I would like to just run the equation in the bound class, but I can't figure out how.

My code might make more sense. I have this simple table:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <td :class="{ threshold: true }">{{ props.item.inventory_amount}}</td>
  <td :class="{ threshold: threshold_hit }">{{ props.item.threshold}}</td>
</template>
```

And then I want to assign the class `threshold` to those rows according to this calculation:

```
props.item.inventory_amount > props.item.threshold
```

This works fine and returns true or false:

```
<td> {{ props.item.inventory_amount > props.item.threshold }}</td>
```

But this fails:

```
<td :class="{ threshold: props.item.inventory_amount > props.item.threshold}">{{ props.item.inventory_amount}}</td>
```

How can I run that equation within the class binding?

Comment: Works fine for me ~ https://jsfiddle.net/p5ynf98u/

Answer (score 0):

Thy this syntax

```js
:class=`{
  '_threshold': props.item.inventory_amount > props.item.threshold
}`
```